# Hide UIToolBar and UINavigation and Expand UIWebView? - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, hide, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to hide a `UIToolBar` and `UINavigationBar` and to do so with a `UITouchGestureRecognizer` but at the same time Expand the `UIWebView` so it takes up the rest of the space?
Also to do the same thing in reverse after?

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
-(void)didTap
{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
//remove your tool bar from superview
[toolbar removeFromSuperview];
//code to add ur UIWebView

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide top navigation bar use either the `navigationBarHidden` property or `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method if you want it animated.  Similarly, use `toolbarHidden` property or `setToolbarHidden:animated:` method for the bottom toolbar.  These are part of `UINavigationController`.

If you want to animate both the toolbars hiding and the `UIWebView` expanding, wrap the change in size of the `UIWebView` in a `UIView animateWithDuration...` method.

Add the gesture recognizer of your choice.  For a swipe, create an instance `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and add it to your view.  Something like this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

And the swipe handler as something like this:

```
-(void)handleSwipe{
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden) {
       [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height - 88);
        }];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height + 88);
       }];
    }
}
```